# How to use a parameter in a recursive method of classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to prepare a tkinter frame in order to display some values of different sensors. I would use Class objects to reuse the code, putting the specific parameters of each sensor. 
Here following, part of my code:

The code works and I get a label with the value updating on regular base but I would create only instances of the class LabelScreen havin the different text and values passed as parameters.

```
class LabelScreen1():
    def __init__(self, parent, text_label, string_var):
        self.string_var = string_var
        larghezza_titolo = 19
        larghezza_labels = 5
        altezza_labels = 2        
        imb_pulsantey = int(1*h)        
        imb_pulsantex = int(1.5*w) 

        self.labelA = tk.Label(
            labels_frame,
            text = "fff",

            width = larghezza_labels,
            height = altezza_labels,
            highlightthickness=2,
            highlightcolor="DodgerBlue2",
            highlightbackground='DodgerBlue2',
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*5)),
            fg="DodgerBlue2",
            background = "gray3",
            pady = imb_pulsantey,
            padx = imb_pulsantex
            )

        self.labelA.place(x=int(w*10), y=int(h*10))

        self.labelA_title = tk.Label(
            labels_frame,
            text = text_label,

            width = larghezza_titolo,
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*1.5)),
            fg="DodgerBlue2",
            background = "gray3",
            )

        self.labelA_title.place(in_=self.labelA, relx=.5, y=int(h*2),anchor="c")        
        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):        
        self.labelA.configure(text=self.string_var.get())#prex_hot)
        self.labelA.after(1000, self.update_label)

class LabelScreen2():
    def __init__(self, parent, text_label):
        larghezza_titolo = 19
        larghezza_labels = 5
        altezza_labels = 2        
        imb_pulsantey = int(1*h)        
        imb_pulsantex = int(1.5*w) 


        self.labelA = tk.Label(
            labels_frame,
            text = "fff",
            width = larghezza_labels,
            height = altezza_labels,
            highlightthickness=2,
            highlightcolor="DodgerBlue2",
            highlightbackground='DodgerBlue2',
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*5)),
            fg="DodgerBlue2",
            background = "gray3",
            pady = imb_pulsantey,
            padx = imb_pulsantex
            )

        self.labelA.place(x=int(w*30), y=int(h*10))

        self.labelA_title = tk.Label(
            labels_frame,
            text = text_label,
            width = larghezza_titolo,
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*1.5)),
            fg="DodgerBlue2",
            background = "gray3",
            )

        self.labelA_title.place(in_=self.labelA, relx=.5, y=int(h*2),anchor="c")        
        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):        
        self.labelA.configure(text=temp1)
        self.labelA.after(1000, self.update_label)

class LabelScreen3():
    def __init__(self, parent, text_label):
        larghezza_titolo = 19
        larghezza_labels = 5
        altezza_labels = 2        
        imb_pulsantey = int(1*h)        
        imb_pulsantex = int(1.5*w) 


        self.labelA = tk.Label(
            labels_frame,
            text = "fff",
            borderwidth=int(h*0.3),            
            width = larghezza_labels,
            height = altezza_labels,
            highlightthickness=2,
            highlightcolor="DodgerBlue2",
            highlightbackground='DodgerBlue2',
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*5)),
            fg="DodgerBlue2",
            background = "gray3",
            pady = imb_pulsantey,
            padx = imb_pulsantex
            )

        self.labelA.place(x=int(w*50), y=int(h*10))

        self.labelA_title = tk.Label(
            labels_frame,
            text = text_label,
            width = larghezza_titolo,
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*1.5)),
            fg="DodgerBlue2",
            background = "gray3",
            )

        self.labelA_title.place(in_=self.labelA, relx=.5, y=int(h*2),anchor="c")        
        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):        
        self.labelA.configure(text=temp2)
        self.labelA.after(1000, self.update_label)

def change_value_randomly(string_var):
    import time
    import random

    while True:
        #string_var.set(random.randint(-10, 10))
        string_var.set(prex_hot)
        time.sleep(1)

radice = tk.Tk()

H=int(radice.winfo_screenheight())
W=int(radice.winfo_screenwidth())
h=int(H/100)
w=int(W/100)
prex_hot=tk.StringVar()

t = threading.Thread(target=change_value_randomly, args=(prex_hot,))
t.start()
screen_resolution = str(W)+'x'+str(H)
radice.geometry(screen_resolution)
labels_frame = tk.Frame(
            radice, background = "black")

labels_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
#labels_frame.pack_propagate(0)
#radice.overrideredirect(1)
label1 = LabelScreen1(radice, "PRESSURE HOT WATER", prex_hot)
label2 = LabelScreen2(radice, "TEMP. EXTERNAL NH")
label3 = LabelScreen3(radice, "TEMP. BOILER")

radice.mainloop()
```

The problem is with the method update_label(self) which I use to get the text (value of the sensor) updated on the screen. In this method you see the variable prex_hot that I would put as parameter of the class. I tried with: def update_label(self, parameter) but as it is recursive I get recursion error. I would pass the parameter to class object but I tried different ways, never worked. Probably the reason is due to the parameter that is a variable itself or probably I'm wrong elsewhere.
Any kind help (forgive me for beginner errors)?

Comment: `after(1000, self.update_label, parameter)` ?

Comment: maybe you should add this in `__init__(..., prex_hot):` and `self.prex_hot = prex_hot` and then `configure(text=self.prex_hot)` but it may not work if this variable keeps text because it will copy text and not keep reference to original variable - so later it will have no access to new text in variable. It would be `StrVar` or element on list to use reference to variable.

Comment: it doesn't work. I already tried with StrVar (even DoubleVar) but it didn't update the variable, that's the reason because I followed the update method. Just for info, I've been using pygame instead of tkinter and I always got any solution I needed. Tkinter is more light (that's the reason of this later choice) but in my opinion is too limited.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses `StringVar`.

`Thread` runs code which use `string_var.set(value)` to set random value in `StringVar`.

At the same time `LabelScreen` uses `string_var.get()` to get value from the same `StringVar` and display it in label.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class LabelScreen():

    def __init__(self, parent, text_label, string_var):
        self.string_var = string_var

        larghezza_titolo = 19
        larghezza_labels = 5
        altezza_labels = 2        
        imb_pulsantey = int(1*h)        
        imb_pulsantex = int(1.5*w) 
        screen_resolution = str(W)+'x'+str(H)
        parent.geometry(screen_resolution)
        self.labels_frame = tk.Frame(parent, background="black")

        self.labels_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.labels_frame.pack_propagate(0)

        self.labelA = tk.Label(
            self.labels_frame,
            text = "fff",
            borderwidth=int(h*0.3),
            width = larghezza_labels,
            height = altezza_labels,
            relief="raised",
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*5)),
            fg="SteelBlue1",
            background = "gray7",
            pady = imb_pulsantey,
            padx = imb_pulsantex
        )

        self.labelA.place(x=int(w*10), y=int(h*10))

        self.labelA_title = tk.Label(
            self.labels_frame,
            text = text_label,
            borderwidth=int(h*0.3),
            width = larghezza_titolo,
            font= ('ObliviousFont',int(h*1.5)),
            fg="SteelBlue1",
            background = "gray7",
        )

        self.labelA_title.place(in_=self.labelA, relx=.5, y=int(h*2),anchor="c")        
        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):        
        self.labelA.configure(text=self.string_var.get())
        self.labelA.after(1000, self.update_label)

# ---------------------------------------------------------

def change_value_randomly(string_var):
    import time
    import random

    while True:
        string_var.set(random.randint(-10, 10))
        time.sleep(1)


radice = tk.Tk()

H=int(radice.winfo_screenheight())
W=int(radice.winfo_screenwidth())
h=int(H/100)
w=int(W/100)
#radice.overrideredirect(1)

prex_hot = tk.StringVar() # after creating `tk.Tk()`

# after creating `StringVar()` but before `mainloop()`
t = threading.Thread(target=change_value_randomly, args=(prex_hot,))
t.start()

label1 = LabelScreen(radice, "PRESSURE HOT WATER", prex_hot)


radice.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works. I edited the original code above. You can see little changes (tk.Frame outside the class and the creation of three classes) that I made before. But most important is the implementation of your suggestion. I now get the variable prex_hot updated but I do not understand how to use the thread for making my variables as parameters of Class. I would create instances with all the parameters inside them and have only one Class. Thanks again